# Laravel virtual host on Xampp does not work properly

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I want to load my Laravel 5.8 project with Virtual Host on XAMPP. So here is what I did:

I opened up `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and put this:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       local.nanoclub.ir
```

Then at `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`, I added this:

```
<VirtualHost local.nanoclub.ir:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/public"
    ServerName local.nanoclub.ir
    ServerAlias *.local.nanoclub.ir
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

And also added this to my project, public `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now when I want to run `local.nanoclub.ir` on browser, I get this:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? I used to access this `local.nanoclub.ir` correctly but now it loads this screen.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's `<VirtualHost *:80>`, restart after making changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache virtual host always redirecting to /dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513297/apache-virtual-host-always-redirecting-to-dashboard)

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant access to this directory.

You can grant this access in your virtual host definition or in the apache2.conf

#### In virtual host definition

```
<VirtualHost local.nanoclub.ir:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/public"
    ServerName local.nanoclub.ir
    ServerAlias *.local.nanoclub.ir
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        # The missing one
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

#### In apache2.conf

```
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Notice**: Don't forget to restart apache after changing configuration.

Comment: Where is apache2.conf?

Comment: @cerealikaeme On Xampp, it is located under `C:/xampp/apache/conf/` as `httpd.conf`

Comment: I add that but still see the same page

Comment: Have you restarted the apache service on xampp panel?

Comment: Yes I have, I have also asked a new bounty question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68516143/laravel-virtual-host-on-xampp-does-not-work-out-properly

Comment: In `http.conf`, where should I add `<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/badges/>...` ? I mean in the beginning or at the end or in the middle? Should I replace it with any other code there?

Comment: Search for a place that has `<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>`. You can add it under that.